# React: How to run a background animation with onClick?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to have a link that when I click it, a CSS animation will start (or change the state of the animation from pause to start). This is how I am doing:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './main_page.css'

function Main() {

    var bg = document.getElementsByClassName('app');

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>
                Welcome to my main page!
            </h1>

            <h2>
                The website is still under development, but please check it out later!
            </h2>

            <p>
                In the mean time, check out my project here! <br></br>
                <Link to = {'/projects/scatter_gather'} onClick = {() => {
                    bg.animationPlayState = 'running';
                }}>
                    Go to "Scatter-Gather"
                </Link>
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

Where the css of .app class is this:

```
.App {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,179,105,0.5) 0%, rgba(245,255,122,0.5) 20%, rgba(121,252,255,0.5) 40%, rgba(83,92,255,0.5) 60%, rgba(255,118,234,0.5) 80%, rgba(255,131,131,0.5) 100%);
  background-size: 400%;
  animation: background_animation 12s infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}

@keyframes background_animation {
  0% {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    background-position:  20%;
  }
  40% {
    background-position: 40%;
  }
  60% {
    background-position: 60%;
  }
  80% {
    background-position: 80%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
}
```

However, when I click on the link, the property is not changing. I believe it's a syntax error? I'm new to this please help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
<p>
                In the mean time, check out my project here! <br></br>
                <Link to = {'/projects/scatter_gather'}>
                    <span onClick={() => {
                    bg.animationPlayState = 'running';
                }}>Go to "Scatter-Gather"</span>
                </Link>
            </p>
```

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I should do the background animation in a different way?